# Linux command cp producing omitted directory

Tags: linux, centos5, cp

I want to place 1 file called "test1.html" in 100 different directories of website.

Directory structure is like the following

/home/domain.com/public_html/ (domain.com name are change for every directory so i use * .

File are here: /root/test1.html

I have try it by : `cp test1.html /home/*/public_html/` via root account but give me

```
cp: omitting directory `/home/domain1.com/public_html/'
cp: omitting directory `/home/domain2.com/public_html/'
```

and so on.

how to place the one file in all domains directory?

it's Centos 5.9

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
for dest in /home/*/public_html/
do 
   cp test1.html $dest
done
```

Since you are writing in user-owned directories be careful of you umask setting - it controls permissions on the file.  You can use `cp -p` to keep the exact permissions on test1.html preserved.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it not make any sense to me. can you please write in more easy way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd /home/; find . -name public_html -type d | xargs -I {} cp /root/test1.html {};
```

Comment: Thanks but not working.  [root@uk ~]# cd /home/; find . -name public_html -type d | xargs -i {} cp /root/googleba3771cddb278c04.html {};
xargs: {}: No such file or directory

Comment: Damn. Its capital i: Edited response

Answer (score -1):

It should be written: `cp -R test1.html /home/*/public_html/`

-R stands for recursive and without it it doesn't want to do all the directories.

Comment: `cp` doesn't support multiple target directories. That's why the other answers use loops or `xargs`, so `cp` can be called many times.

Comment: Those other answers didn't work for me, but this did.

Comment: Sounds like you are copying **from** one or more directories, in which case `-R` is the right answer. In this question the OP was trying to copy **to** a bunch of directories. `-R` doesn't help with that.